# Invalid session cookie is not invalidated or replaced?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, session-cookies

In ASP.NET i was having a strange situation where `Session_Start` was being triggered every time the user-agent refreshed the page. Since a session should have already been started, i couldn't understand why (this one machine) was triggering a `Session_Start` every page hit.

The browser was sending a cookie as part of the HTTP request:

```
GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
...
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=zsdntozy30cwvirc3lpnxh55
```

The cookie was present in the http **request** header, yet it was causing a new session to be created. Maddeningly though, the new `Cookie` was not being sent to the client (through the `Set-Cookie` response header).

i *assume* that if the session cookie `ASP.NET_SessionId=zsdntozy30cwvirc3lpnxh55` is not valid (e.g. due to an application pool recycle, or web-server restart) then the server *should* `set` a new cookie.

To test this i crafted a special http request, with an obviously invalid cookie:

```
GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
...
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Sure enough, the `Session_Start` event happens, and the http **response** contains no `Set-Cookie` header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 24 Mar 2011 23:45:50 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3710
Connection: Close
```

Is this intended behavior? If the client's session cookie is no longer valid, they'll be stuck in some no-mans land until the client browser is convinced to destroy the cookie?

Is there an option for ASP.NET to sent the **new** session cookie to the client? It is, after all, **creating** a new session - why not tell the client about it?

Is this some bizarre security feature, where a user must delete all cookies if a server gets the hiccups?

Comment: deleted SU's version of this question. Good luck!